# Law/Ethics question in regards to content distribution

Tags: discussion, etiquette, site-promotion, legal

I've been wanting to start up a youtube channel for a while and my recent fun writing riddles for this site has been awesome. If I make a youtube channel featuring the riddles I write here and put a link to the puzzling version in the description, would it in any way be a problem? Would it help the site as well as myself?

Also, is it okay to post others' original riddles with their consent and what constitutes proof of consent for the standards of the community should a later disagreement arise?

If I want to share the channel with people on this site to generate a following, are there any acceptable means of self-promotion?

Comment: let us know the channel at some point :)

Comment: How should I go about it? Is it only okay to go into the chat and to put it in my profile, or is there more it would be acceptable to do?

Comment: Actually I don't know. Maybe that should even be a question of its own. I've never seen such as case - people normally put such links in their profile indeed.

Comment: I just don't want to be a jerk. I respect what the stack exchange community is, and I respect what puzzling could become. I also worry that excessive allowances could set a catastrophic precedence. I would love the marketing boost that comes from self-promotion and any great effects that such would have on our community, but not at the expense of that community.

Answer (score 5):

All user-generated content on Stack Exchange is [licensed under Creative Commons with attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). So as long as you follow the attribution rules there, yes, you should be perfectly fine.

Comment: What if the content is from a source other than the stack first? Does that change the rights usage? Would it be different if the contents source and the poster were different entities? Is there any problem with my monetizing my own content via sites like youtube?

Comment: But for his own material, he does not need to do any attribution, as explained in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203299/202205

Comment: @Travis You may want to just use the [contact us] link at the bottom of the page. Make sure you read through the Creative Commons overview, and email them if you have questions.

Comment: @TravisKindred If the content was posted on SE from an external source and it can't be used under SE's licensing terms, then it must be removed from SE. However moderators are not judges of copyright law, so do not flag for such cases (do flag for *plagiarism*, i.e. third-party content without attribution). If you republish something originally published under a different license, you're the one who's taking the legal risk, it's up to you to decide whether you want to take this risk.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I've got a much better understanding.